# SharePoint 2010 Remove server from a Farm by force?

Tags: sharepoint, server-farm

I am trying to remove on of the servers on My farms but I ma not able to do it ,please check this Image :

[image]

When I Click on "remove Server" I get this error : 
An object in the SharePoint administrative framework, "SPDatabaseServiceInstance", could not be deleted because other objects depend on it.  Update all of these dependents to point to null or different objects and retry this operation

[image]

Or at less is there a way to know what are the dependents on that server ?

thanks and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, I would connect to the database server to remove and using Management Studio I would check if there is some sharepoint databases running.

Then you can move existing databases to another sql server.
This post helped me a lot to do it :
http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=255
(it is for sharepoint 2007 but process is the same)